# select input inside list based on value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following list

[image]

and I need to disable the radio button with a specific value
how can I do that using JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(":radio[value=15]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Edited 'attr' to 'prop' method, thanks Ashraf Bashir

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the jquery selector for the radio buttons only inside your 'ulTeams', use the following selector:

```
$("#ulTeams :radio[value=15]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

[see @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/infantrash/tefSg/)

Comment: For more info, kindly check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery >= 1.6:

```
var desiredValue = 10; // or whatever value you need to disable
$("input[type=radio][value=" + desiredValue + "]").prop("disabled",true);
```

& If you are using jQuery < 1.6 do this:

```
var desiredValue = 10; // or whatever value you need to disable
$("input[type=radio][value=" + desiredValue + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: I need to select the elements that are only inside the ul not all radio elements I have others with the same values also

Comment: keep one class for all radio's inside ul and then check with value and then attr/prop disabled......... by this all the input type radio will be disabled if more then one has same value on same page.